# How do you solve the iPhone error "signature is valid but not trusted"?

Tags: iphone, signature, provisioning

Finally got MGTwitterEngine stuff to

**compile** (*by setting the Header Search Paths to /usr/include/libxml2  iphoneos3.0/usr/lib/libxml2*)

AND **link** (*by removing the Twitter LibXML Parsers code and assigning a weak role to libxml2.2.dylib in Targets: Link Binary With Libraries*).

But when I do a **Build and Go to the iPhone** (*not the simulator*), I get this error:

"*This provisioning profile does not have a valid signature (or it has a valid, but untrusted signature).*"

I have followed the official Apple Developer process of getting a certificate and provisioning, etc. Obviously, I did something wrong somewhere. Has anyone come across this problem or have any ideas on how to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Things to check:

1. In Keychain Access, make sure you have a code sign identity (public and private keys and a certificate titled "iPhone Developer: Your Name"
2. In your Info.plist, make sure your Bundle Identifier matches your App ID that you created in the dev portal
3. Make sure you installed the .mobileprovision (from Terminal> open x.mobileprovision)
4. In the dev portal, make sure your provisioning profile has your certificate, your App ID, and your device all enabled.  If it doesn't, fix that and re-download and re-install your provisioning profile.
5. Follow the instructions very carefully when creating your Certificate. One time, in Keychain Access, when I went to Request a Certificate, I had something else selected in the list panel and so it created the wrong kind of certificate. Make sure nothing in the list is selected when you do this part.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into this right now. But I just have to say I love your screen name! I don't know why but I'm just smiling my fool head off at it. (alternate interpretation: "select all" LOL)

Comment: OK, the thing is my boss signed up for the dev program so the certificate reads iPhone developer: HIM. But the private key underneath is ME. Can I change that? Or can I work with that? I'll try stuff while I wait with hope.

Comment: OK, I went through the whole thing again, this time I used my boss' name and I did the App ID right ;-p so things looked better. I set the field in the plist properly. The problem is when I add the provisioning file in Organizer, it tells me "A valid signing identity matching this profile could not be found in your keychain." Ack!

Comment: Troy - Do you have a public and private key pair titled "His Name", and also a Certificate called "iPhone Developer: His Name"?  If so, then make sure that your provisioning profile (on the dev portal) has His Name checked as a Certificate. Then re-download it and install it.

Answer (score 1):

Restarting Xcode may also work... (Work for me couple of times)

Answer (score 0):

Troy It looks like the issue is you don't have a keypair that is tied to the provisioning profile installed. It's tough to tell for sure but that is my best guess.

If that is the case, I've been working in a similar situation - what you need is to either generate a private key using the iphone development portal under the same account your boss used and then add that new key to the provisioning profile you are building with.
OR
You can get your boss to export the key he generated when he created the provisioning profile - he can export it from keychain and give it a password that will allow you to install it but protect it from anyone else installing it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the fifth time's the charm. I basically deleted the certificate and the provisioning file, etc., and started completely over. Viola! Now for those pesky memory leaks! :-) Oh, Java, wherefore art thou, Java? (and your majic garbage collection!)

Answer (score 0):

One of the things that I tried and worked for me was to reset the keychain access
http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1544